# Is there a term for lore about a game world's population (cultures, economic state, etc.)?

Tags: terminology, npc, world-design

The lore of a game, the ethnicity of its population, cultures, economic state or anything which illustrates the population of a game.

Are all these things part of the lore? Or are they called the story of the game?

Comment: It sounds like you might want to say the game's internal demographic?

Comment: Fortunately, the word Lore can encompass many things. I would say yes, it could be world history, etc. If you're looking for synonyms or something more I would suggest asking this on the English stack exchange site.

Answer (score 2):

"Lore" is a very broad phase. For example, let's take the Elder Scrolls games. They have a lore which describes almost everything. The gods, the history, the people and races, the population and the regions are also part of it.

If something is used to describe the way and reason how the world functions, then it's part of the lore.